# Avoid fixed page element "shift" when removing scrollbars on body?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I'm trying to solve what could be an annoying problem, and I'm sure there is a solution I couldn't find yet. I've read a lot of articles like [Prevent Page Scrolling When a Modal is Open](https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/) but none of them speak about the **fixed element "shift"**.

What is a fixed element shift? See [my pen](https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/XWqmzZy): click on the hamburger icon and you'll see that **the red button itself will "shift"** to the right.

[image: Fixed elements layout shift]

When the full screen menu opens, I alter the body style via JavaScript, setting `overflow` and `padding-right`:

- ✅ Avoid body content "shift" (blue content): this is solved setting body `padding-right` equal to the current scrollbar width.
- Avoid **fixed elements "shift"** (red button): i couldn't avoid this.

```js
const openMenu = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // ...
  
  // Change body style
  Object.assign(document.body.style, {
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'padding-right': `${window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth}px`,
  });
};

const closeMenu = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // ...
  
  // Remove body style
  document.body.removeAttribute('style');
};
```

**EDIT**: happens in Chrome 105, Edge 105 on Windows. Doesn't happen in Firefox 104.

Comment: does `html { scrollbar-gutter: stable; }` help?

Comment: Would you set it in the openMenu function right?

Comment: no, I would set that in CSS once - not conditionally, just set it and forget it - but I may have misunderstood the issue

Comment: Oh I see. Anyways, it doesn't help. When scrollbar-gutter is stable, I can avoid setting body padding-right... but still, fixed content shifts :(

Comment: The codepen doesn't illustrate your issue though - oh, sorry, this seems to NOT be an issue in Firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX you right! Fixed elements remain in place with Firefox... so strange then. I'll update the question with an animated gif

Comment: You should not remove the scrollbar. This is the main problem and makes a bad UX.

Comment: @ErfanAtp thanks, any solution to avoid scrolling then?

Comment: yeah, I can see that the scrollbar-gutter does naff all in chrome - I'm probably confused what that is used for -

Comment: teh hacky way to do it is to add `.style.right='41px'` when the menu opens and `.style.right=''` when it closes - though, that 41px may not work for everyone (it's the 24px of right-6 + 17px for the scrollbar, by the way)

Comment: another way - rather than setting `right-6` class ... set style `left: calc(100vw - 97px);` so that's 24px + width of button (56px) + 17px for the scrollbar - again, that 17px may be a magic number that doesn't always work

Comment: Using a fixed position is enough! What do you want more? @gremo

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```html
html,
body {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in Chrome (also Edge and other Chromium-based browsers), see https://crbug.com/1251856

Firefox currently has the correct, expected behavior.